# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data' when using peripheral.writeValue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cbperipheral

I've successfully created an app that scans for peripherals, finds the device of device name I want to connect to, discovers its services and characterises and connects to the device.

A UIButton when clicked should send the string "rw w45,80" to the device I'm connected to through the characteristic F0001131-0451-4000-B000-000000000000, which is the write characteristic of service F0001131-0450-4000-B000-000000000000.

I get the following error:
[image]

I know the issue is in the data types and that it's expecting type 'Data' but I have no idea where to begin.

I use a BLE Scanner app to send such strings to the device with no issues as below. I'm trying to get my app to send similar strings:

[image]

Comment: You need to convert your String in to data, like type casting...

Comment: @iOS Converting a string to data is nothing like type casting.